# .NET Portability Analyzer doesn't match .NET API Browser results

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a conflicting results between the .NET Portability Analyzer (VS extension) and the official .NET API Browser: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api

When analyzing a .NET Framework assembly with the portability analyzer, I have the following result for the type System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess:

[image]

This would suggest that the type is only available in the upcoming 3.0 release of .NET Core. However when using the aforementioned API browser, it clearly states that the type is already available in version .NET Core version 2.0.

I prefer to trust the API browser, but I just wondered if anyone had a different interpretation of the output given by the portability analyzer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. The type will be part of .NET Core 3.0, it does not ship as part of .NET Core 2.0 or 2.1, but is available via an additional NuGet package ([System.Security.Permissions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Permissions/)).

The tools and documentation may have a different view on what is "part of" a particular version of .NET Core and what is "usable" in some way on a particular version.

An additional source you can check is apisof.net: https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess
which correctly lists the type as .NET Core 3.0 and ".NET Core + Platform Extensions" 2.0 and 2.1

Comment: Ok I understand now. Indeed, I found in the analyzer settings the options ".NET Core/Standard + Platform Extensions". When checked, the resultant column is consistent with the results found with the API Browser. Thanks also for the additional resource.