# How do I tell what is "really" supported on .NET Core? For example the registry

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, registry, portability

I have a C# library that I want to port from .NET Framework to .NET Core.  So I ran Visual Studio's "Portability Analyzer" against it, and it tagged several unsupported things for me to deal with.  But I was surprised at some of the things that it did *not* tag, including registry-related stuff (this is just an example - I intend my question to be broader than just the registry).

I thought that I had always previously read that the registry is one of the things that is unsupported on platforms other than Windows.  So I thought maybe the Portability Analyzer was just wrong about it.  But then I went to Microsoft's website and looked up some of the registry-related things that I was surprised by, and found that they are included in .NET Core.  For example:

[Microsoft.Win32.Registry, .NET Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?view=netcore-2.1)

But I thought that the main point of .NET Core was to have a cross-platform implementation of .NET Standard, and that things like the registry would not be in .NET Core, but instead in ".NET Core plus Platform Extensions" (if anywhere).  So I'm clearly misunderstanding something here.

Perhaps the functions are implemented but will just throw exceptions on non-Windows OSes? Or be essentially no-op?  If something like that is the case, how can I tell whether or not the library will "really" work on other platforms (short of explicit trial and error)? I thought that was the whole point of the Portability Analyzer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Portability Analyzer doesn't match .NET API Browser results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53390956/net-portability-analyzer-doesnt-match-net-api-browser-results)

Answer (score 0):

learn.microsoft.com isn't a good resource for figuring out where a component fits. Use https://apisof.net for that. For example https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.Win32.Registry tells us that `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` is in:

- .NET Core 3.0
- .NET Core + Platform Extensions 2.0 and 2.1
- .NET Standard + Platform Extensions 1.6 and 2.0
- ASP.NET Core 2.0
- .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks, but then is the Visual Studio Portability Analyzer just wrong? And is there any tool that is like it except not wrong?